# Validation on 2 radio groups jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button, radio-group

I need guidance with a validation with 2 radio groups, I have a questionnaire with 28 questions and 2 sets of answers with radios inputs, the thing is I want to validate that the answer in the same row wont be the same on both answers, I'm attaching a screenshot, the invalid answers are boxed in red.

[image: Radio validation]

I want to do the validation via jquery, I hope someone can help me.

Here's the mark up:

```
<input type="radio" name="most_option_1" id="q1_most_option_id_1" value="D">
<input type="radio" name="least_option_1" id="q1_least_option_id_1" value="C">
```

Answer (score 0):

if radio buttons have the same name you will not be able to select both but only one or the other. All you need to make sure is that every "row" in your questionnaire has a unique name for both radio buttons. No Javascript required.

something like:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <th>#1</th>
  <th>Most</th>
  <th>Least</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Enthusiastic</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="q1_enthusiastic" value="D"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="q1_enthusiastic" value="C"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Daring</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="q1_daring" value="D"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="q1_daring" value="C"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Diplomatic</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="q1_diplomatic" value="D"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="q1_diplomatic" value="C"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Satisfied</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="q1_satisfied" value="D"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="q1_satisfied" value="C"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/z1kcmwuq/1/

Comment: sure : 

<input type="radio" name="most_option_1'" id="q1_most_option_id_1" value="D'">                                 
<input type="radio" name="least_option_1" id="q1_least_option_id_1" value="'C" >

Comment: it sounds like you need to rethink your markup, as you are not using radio buttons the way they are intended, which will lead to a lot of additional jquery to validate something that radio buttons are meant to do by default

Comment: I thought using 2 different radio buttons I was able to compare that the answers don't collide on the same row for each question. I don't want both answers in the same row.

Comment: Correct, but you need to give them the same name within a row, that way they will ensure the answer won't collide. I have updated my fiddle & answer

Comment: Perhaps I could do a index search for each group and then compare them, that the same index number are not selected

Comment: You could, but that to me seems like a bad design, seeing you are not using radio buttons properly